# groovy on Raring

Tags: ros, installation, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys,
I am having a lot of dependency issues for ROS installation on Raring.

Will there be a release of Groovy on raring, or will ROS move onto Hydro Medusa directly?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56556/groovy-on-raring/) by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 528 on 2013-02-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, Groovy will not support Raring. Yes, Hydro Medusa will. But, note that Raring will probably have issues with packages not yet supporting Python 3.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on 2013-03-03**:
Thanks joq. Yes, I spent some time and I ended up with the same conclusion. There are dependencies on older versions of basic ubuntu desktop libraries such as libice which makes groovy unsuitable for raring.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please refer to [REP 3](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rep/blob/master/rep-0003.rst): Target platforms.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2013-02-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2